# PHP with mysqli_real_escape_string does not work as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to create a login page but I have a problem where the data is not being sent. Can any one help me out.

```
  $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA1('$mypassword')";
    $result=mysql_query($dbC, $sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
        session_register("admin");
        session_register("password");
        $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
        header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else {

        $msg = "$username $password $myusername $mypassword $sql $result Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
```

And the output I get is:
test test123 SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name=\'\' and user_pass=SHA1(\'\') Wrong Username or Password. Please retry

Comment: `mysqli` has prepared statements too, I suggest you use them.

Comment: As do I, @Jack. so much can go wrong with escaping, so the simplest thing to do is simply to not require it and make the SQL engine smarter (i.e. using the `Prepare` statement in the api instead of `Query`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to supply a $link identifier as the first argument in [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) so those lines should look more like

```
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$mypassword);
```

where $dbconn is the link you get back from `mysqli_connect`. You're also using mysql_query and mysql_num_rows when you should be using their mysqli_ equivalents if you're going to be switching to the mysqli_* set of functions.

I'd strongly recommend switching to mysqli (or PDO) over using the (now legacy) mysql functions. PHP.net provides [information](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) about why.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the (wonderful) thing that we like to call [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
These are great in that they **treat data as data, not as a statement to be executed**. This means that escaping isnt needed, because your input cannot be misinterpreted.

To implement this in your case:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_name FROM login_admin WHERE user_name = ? AND user_pass = SHA1(?)";
if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)) { //returns false if incorrect syntax, error, etc.
    $query->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    // ss = string, string
    // mixed bind_param($params, **args);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($u);
    $query->fetch();
    $query->close();
} else {
    /* error handling */
}
if ($u) {
    /* session setting */
    header("Location: admin.php");
} else {
    header("Location: login.php?e=1");
}
```

I also have a working [admin control panel](https://github.com/HirotoKun/admin-panel) I wrote that I copy-paste into things that implements pretty much anything for a login system (see [`private.php`](https://github.com/HirotoKun/admin-panel/blob/master/admin/private.php))

Also, to answer your real question, there is no such way to do an escape in mysqli without a database connection. Add your database to the start of the function:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $string);
```